# Setting the 'audience' in a SharePoint-NavigationNode?

Tags: sharepoint

Hallo, i am using WSS 3.0 and i need to display certain entries of a website's navigation ("Quicklaunch") to specified groups only. According to [this blogpost](http://www.mtelligent.com/journal/2007/10/7/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-with-spnavigationnode-spna.html) this can be done using properties of the SPNavigationNode - but it seems the solution to the problem is 'MOSS only'. Is there a way to do this in WSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QuickLaunch (QL) will do security trimming for the default items on the menu. In other words, if a user doesn't have access to what the QL nav item points to, it won't be displayed to her. However, the QL unfortunately does **not** do security trimming on nav items you add manually through the GUI. If you add items via the object model and indicate that they should be security-trimmed, it will work.

I was able to both add and remove security-trimmed QL nav items to WSS using the code in this [blog post](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/tbaginski/archive/2007/12/26/how-to-programmatically-customize-site-navigation-in-wss-3-0-and-moss-2007.aspx). (Actually, I did it via PowerShell, but that's still using the same object model code.) I hope that helps.